# How can i follow progression of code coverage

Tags: php, code-coverage, php-code-coverage

I currently use the [php-code-coverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage) tool and i m wondering if there is a opensource tool to journalize the code-coverage day by day (or tests by tests)

I would like to track the progress or regress of code-coverage.

At each run of my tests i generate a report of code coverage, but i m not able to track the diff between the current report and the last report , excepted if i track manually the code coverage.

Comment: You could generate the report and commit it to its own repository using git. That way, you would be able to keep track of your progress and check out how it was in the past.

Comment: @diegow yes i can do this, but this is not optimal, i would like the keep the details of the code coverage into one view. i don't want to pass from report to report to check the diff.